# How to remove tub drain?

Tags: drain, bathtub

Take a look at attached picture of my tub drain which is corroded.

I tried [this tool](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-Tub-Drain-Removal-Tool-410-075-0111/311493720?g_store=921&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D26P-026_007_PLUMB_REPAIR-NA-MULTI-NA-SMART-2998850-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PL3_Live&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D26P-026_007_PLUMB_REPAIR-NA-MULTI-NA-SMART-2998850-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PL3_Live-71700000094213688-58700007814434194-92700071019453814&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIqqf-4a_P-QIVWgOzAB32wwuWEAQYASABEgJbTPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) with no avail.

When I used more force with that tool, some pieces broke apart from it.

Now I ended up with what you see in picture. Red arrow is pointing to remaining piece of metal drain flange, which is stuck inside PVC drain pipe  where blue arrow is pointing.

1. how can I remove remaining metal piece? If I use hammer and screw driver to break it apart, I am worried that it can damage PVC plumbing work.
2. In the process, black rubber gasket came out from area between tub and PVC drain. Did I remove the part I wasn't supposed to ?
3. I can seethe gap between tub and PVC drain pipe. wondering how am I going to seal that gap. With new rubber gasket ?

[image: drain]

Comment: You may need to come through the floor from below or come through a wall to access this, if you are not pulling the tub. Most things will break if you apply enough force, and the repair gets more extensive when you break things...

Comment: You need to get that old rubber gasket (or a new one) back in between the tub and the flange of the waste pipe. That's what makes the seal to keep the water from leaking.

Comment: google `golden extractor`

Comment: you removed the center part (with screw in the middle). HOW

Comment: That part is not screwed in, It is a rubber gasket insert. However you bathtub has seen its days and is rusting at that flange, not sure it can be repaired.

Answer (score 2):

The way to safely remove the remaining metal part is to use a tool like this:

[image]
<sub>Picture Source: My Garage</sub>

Use the free end of the hack saw blade to cut in vertical direction from the inside of the remaining metal ring. Cut carefully to avoid cutting into the PVC pipe.

Often it is necessary to make several cuts around the perimeter. When the saw has cut almost all the way through it is often possible to then insert a small flat blade screw driver near the cut and a twist will tear the remaining portion of the cut area open. The metal ring should then just peel away. Be careful not to drop pieces down the drain.

Comment: Care should also be taken to not cut into the tub. And I love the picture credit! ;)

Comment: I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

There are other tools similar to the one you referenced in your post.  I would try them before you risk ruining the tub with a hacksaw.   Search for "inside out pipe wrench" or "internal pipe wrench".

[https://www.amazon.com/RIDGID-31405-Internal-Wrench-2-inch/dp/B0015B9SF6/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=inside+out+wrench&qid=1660832015&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015B9SF6)

[image]